# Why can't connect my vps ip via firefox?

Tags: vps

I have installed lamp on my new bought bandwagon host  vps ip ,and edit an file named echo.php in /var/www/ .

The content in echo.php is:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

In the console , `php  /var/www/echo.php` can list php info for me.
why `http://vps_ip/echo.php` (input in firefox) list nothing for me?

```
ssh  root@vps_ip:28662
```

Error info:
ssh: could not resolve hostname

It is so strange that the vps_ip can be connected by putty!

Comment: Did you make sure that /var/www is the document root of your webserver? It used to be /var/www/html in apache. Also, is it giving you blank page or 404?

Answer (score 0):

Check the apache error_log for issues.
Generally either /var/log/apache/error_log or /var/log/httpd/error_log

Can you confirm that the path /var/www is the actual document root.
I would suggest creating another file in plain text at that location and verify that it works.  eg: echo "Test Me" >/var/www/test.txt

The plain text file will at least confirm that the folder/files are in the correct places and that you may have another problem with php.